# Calculate a Cumulative Sum of object's values for each Object in a List with stream API

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to implement a *cumulative sum* of the values of Objects from a *list*.

The Object looks as shown below:

```
public class NameValuePair {
    private String name;
    private int value;
}
```

I have a `List<NameValuePair>` as input.

And the result should be also a `List<NameValuePair>` with the *cumulated values*, i.e. every subsequent *value* should be summed with the total obtained so far.

How can I achieve it with Java Stream API?

An input sample would be:

```
("a", 2), ("b", 12), ("c", 15), ("d", 20)
```

And the desired output would be:

```
("a", 2), ("b", 14), ("c", 29), ("d", 49)
```

Comment: A sample input, the desired output, and your own previous attempts would give the question more relevance.

Comment: You have to use the Stream API for this? It would be pretty simple to do a traditional for loop to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AtomicInteger to store the cumulated value:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


....


List<NameValuePair> list = List.of( new NameValuePair("a", 2),
                                    new NameValuePair("b", 12),
                                    new NameValuePair("c", 15),
                                    new NameValuePair("d", 20));

AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

List<NameValuePair> result = list.stream()
                                 .map(nvp -> new NameValuePair(nvp.getName(), ai.addAndGet(nvp.getValue())))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Using a stateful behavior in stateless operations is discouraged. Use reduction (of which collection is a specialization) instead. See the docs for the java.util.stream package.

Answer (score 1):

The process of accumulating values can be handled inside a *collector*.

In this case, there would be no need for storing the *current value* outside the stream-pipeline and updating it via *side effects*, which isn't encouraged by the [*API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

#### Custom Collector

For that, we need to define a *custom collector*. Which could be implemented as a class implementing `Collector` interface, or we can make use of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

These are *parameters* expected by the `Collector.of()`:

- **Supplier** `Supplier<A>` is meant to provide a *mutable container* which store elements of the stream. In this case, `ArrayDeque` (as an implementation of the `Deque` interface) will be handy as a *container* to facilitate the convenient access to the previously added element.
- **Accumulator** `BiConsumer<A,T>` defines how to add elements into the *container* provided by the *supplier*. In the accumulator to we need to make sure that the *deque* is not empty before accessing the last element. ***Note:*** pairs in the solution provided below are treated as immutable (and I've reimplemented as a *record*), therefore the very first pair is used as is, the others would be reinstaintiated.
- **Combiner** `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()` establishes a rule on how to merge the two *containers* obtained while executing stream in parallel. This task can is sequential by its nature, it doesn't make sense splitting it into subtasks and executed in parallel. For that reason, the *combiner* is implemented to throw an `AssertionError` in case of parallel execution.
- **Finisher** `Function<A,R>` is meant to produce the final result by transforming the *mutable container*. The *finisher* function in the code below turns the *container* (the *deque* containing the result), into an *immutable list*.
- **Characteristics** allow providing additional information, for instance `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` which is used in this case denotes that the order in which partial results of the reduction produced while executing in parallel is not significant. This *collector* doesn't require any characteristics.

#### Implementation

```
public static List<NameValuePair> accumulateValues(List<NameValuePair> pairs) {
    return pairs.stream()
        .collect(getPairAccumulator());
}

public static Collector<NameValuePair, ?, List<NameValuePair>> getPairAccumulator() {
    
    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new, // mutable container
        (Deque<NameValuePair> deque, NameValuePair pair) -> {
            if (deque.isEmpty()) deque.add(pair);
            else deque.add(new NameValuePair(pair.name(), deque.getLast().value() + pair.value()));
        },
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("should not be executed in parallel"); }, // combiner - function responsible 
        (Deque<NameValuePair> deque) -> deque.stream().toList() // finisher function
    );
}
```

If you're using Java 16 or above, you can implement `NameValuePair` as a [*record*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395):

```
public record NameValuePair(String name, int value) {}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<NameValuePair> pairs =
        List.of(new NameValuePair("a", 2), new NameValuePair("b", 12),
                new NameValuePair("c", 15), new NameValuePair("d", 20));

    List<NameValuePair> result = accumulateValues(pairs);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
NameValuePair[name=a, value=2]
NameValuePair[name=b, value=14]
NameValuePair[name=c, value=29]
NameValuePair[name=d, value=49]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rQG)